# Pushing view controller within block not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, objective-c-blocks

What is the correct way to fire methods within a completion block (if this is even recommended)? Right now, I have an IBAction that calls a method that downloads information with a completion block signifying if the info was retrieved successfully or not. If it was, I want to push a view controller that will display that information, but at the moment, nothing is happening. I'm guessing it has something to do with main thread, gcd, etc...

```
__weak YTTMSetupViewController *weakSelf = self;
    [mc downloadJson:^(BOOL success) {
            if(success){
                NSLog(@"sucess. metric count - %i",(int)mc.collection.count);

                //info was downloaded. Push new view controller with info
                YTTMMetricTableViewController *mtvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YTTMMetricTableViewController"];
                mtvc.group = (WAGroup*)[[WAMetricCollection sharedInstance].collection lastObject];
                mtvc.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
                [weakSelf.navigationController pushViewController:mtvc animated:YES];
            }
            else{
                NSLog(@"failure");
                //display failure UI
            }
            NSLog(@"end of downloading");
            [HUD dismissAfterDelay:0.5f animated:YES];
        }];
```

Comment: You can try call pushViewController from dispatch_asynch with delay 0.0 sec. Usually, it work.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the right way to do it, but it worked.

I added a method that will push the vc on the main thread as so:

```
        [weakSelf performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(pushDetail) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

Completed Code:

```
__weak YTTMSetupViewController *weakSelf = self;
    [mc downloadJson:^(BOOL success) {
            if(success){
                NSLog(@"sucess. metric count - %i",(int)mc.collection.count);

                //info was downloaded. Push new view controller with info
                [weakSelf performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(pushDetail) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
            }
            else{
                NSLog(@"failure");
                //display failure UI
            }
            NSLog(@"end of downloading");            
        }];

}

-(void)pushDetail{
    __weak YTTMSetupViewController *weakSelf = self;
    YTTMMetricTableViewController *mtvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YTTMMetricTableViewController"];
    mtvc.group = (WAGroup*)[[WAMetricCollection sharedInstance].collection lastObject];
    mtvc.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    [weakSelf.navigationController pushViewController:mtvc animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply try wrapping the call with a dispatch_asynch block...

```
__weak YTTMSetupViewController *weakSelf = self;
    [mc downloadJson:^(BOOL success) {
        if(success){
            NSLog(@"sucess. metric count - %i",(int)mc.collection.count);

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                //info was downloaded. Push new view controller with info
                YTTMMetricTableViewController *mtvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YTTMMetricTableViewController"];
                mtvc.group = (WAGroup*)[[WAMetricCollection sharedInstance].collection lastObject];
                mtvc.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
                [weakSelf.navigationController pushViewController:mtvc animated:YES];
            });
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"failure");
            //display failure UI
        }
        NSLog(@"end of downloading");
        [HUD dismissAfterDelay:0.5f animated:YES];
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

All UI updates must be performed on the main thread. Personally I prefer to do this through [GCD](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html) as it produces more readable code than `performSelectorOnMainThread`. However, there's nothing wrong with `performSelectorOnMainThread` aside from personal preference in the case of calling a single UI update on the main thread following the execution of some completion block. Do note that, whichever one you choose, you should [be consistent with what you use to guarantee that blocks are enqueued in the order you specified](http://blackpixel.com/blog/2013/11/performselectoronmainthread-vs-dispatch-async.html).

Working code aside, however, the convention Apple's frameworks seem to use is to perform all completion blocks on the main thread unless a queue is specified as a method parameter, in which case the completion block should be performed on that queue. So in this case I would recommend you edit your download handler class's `downloadJson` method to automatically perform the completion block on the main queue.